# fire click function after another (within modals)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying the below; it is failing with error '`Message: element not intractable`'. Presumably because Python is trying to fire them both at the same time.

The first one works. But, the second one is failing. I just tried using `sleep` in between and the `implicity_wait` below. The scenerio is one modal dialog box after another. Click first 'button', second modal shows (basically a confirm screen) > won't click that button.

```
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#publishButton").click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-primary").click()
```

Here is the mark-up; of the second button I am trying to access.

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" ng-click="save();">Save As Pending</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting for longer than 4 seconds (e.g. 10 seconds) to see if it responds then?

Comment: FYI `implicitly_wait()` doesn't actually wait when called. It just sets the timeout for the driver. You should read the docs to better understand how it works. You should also prefer `WebDriverWait` to do waits and not use `implicitly_wait()` per the Selenium contributors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try WebDriverWait and visibility of the second button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-mini.btn-primary"))).click()
```

You need to have the following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: thanks; it is now saying 'name 'driver' is not defined' with this. I just tried adding '.self' as well..

Comment: object has no attribute 'WebDriverWait'

Comment: @PeterGibbons : updated the option can you try now and please import all above as i mentioned.